# images not accessible from public storage folder

Tags: php, laravel, file-storage

I try to access an image that is in following location:

`storage/app/public/uploads/myImageIsHere.jpeg`

I have tried all stack overflow options, public_path, Storage::url, creating a symlink link and thousands others.

Can someone explain me how to access this image in my .blade file ??

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url("app/sponsors/8R4HnbOzDdUilnSaZSRj9VzmeI7oKI9JrCWe3rgY.jpeg") }}">

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/sponsors/8R4HnbOzDdUilnSaZSRj9VzmeI7oKI9JrCWe3rgY.jpeg 404 (Not Found)
```

And this returns a correct path according to my img src path.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the version of laravel you are using ? And what is the error message that you get?

Comment: @Vagabond 6.3.0

Comment: What is the error message that you receive ?

Comment: @Vagabond well the console returns a 404 of image not found, no laravel error in the UI ...

Comment: Can you show what you tried ?

Comment: Did you check this? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem

Comment: When you create symlink the storage are linked to public folder folders which are accessible by as in your case it's uploads, so its `domain.com/uploads/image.jpg` , no need to go to storage file path. If blade is in route just use `/uploads/image.jpg`, if somewhere else then use app url along

Comment: can you take a look again? i update my post @Vagabond

Comment: @Manjunath, problem solved thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try ,

Storage::get("app/public/uploads/myImageIsHere.jpeg");

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
<img src="{{ URL::to("/images/abc.jpg") }}">
```

this will return an image namely abc.jpg inside "public/images" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan storage:link` to create a symlink to your [public storage disk](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#the-public-disk). After that you can access your image like that:

```html
<img src="{{ 'storage/uploads/8R4HnbOzDdUilnSaZSRj9VzmeI7oKI9JrCWe3rgY.jpeg' }}">
```